# Xml parh ordenar por el id y no por orden alfabetico

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, xpath, pivot

Estoy creando un pivot en sql y necesito que @columnas que es la variable donde están mis columnas estén en orden de id

ID  description
1   rapido
2   fuerte
3   bonito
4   autentico

con el código que tengo me queda de esta forma

autentico | bonito | fuerte | rápido

pero me gustaría saber que cambio tengo que hacer para que quede así es decir escorado por el id

rápido | fuerte | bonito | autentico

```
declare @columnas varchar(2000) =  stuff((select distinct '],[' +  
description from v_questionanswered  order by '],[' + description for xml path('')),1,2,'' ) 
+ ']'
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes invertir el orden de la query

```
declare @columnas varchar(2000) =  stuff((select distinct '],[' +  
description from v_questionanswered  order by '],[' + description desc for xml 
path('')),1,2,'' ) 
+ ']'
```

o donde dice order by '],[' + description ... por order by '],[' + id